# A simple Read-Write huge input file problem

Tags: c#, regex

As title, I'm trying to replace 2 or more space between characters into a single space.  The following code works, however, not for very large input file.   How can I make it works for huge input file as well?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}");   //Pattern = 2 or more space in a string.

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\CSharpProject\in\abc.txt");
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        content = pattern.Replace(content, @" ");   //Replace 2 or more space into a single space.
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\CSharpProject\out\abc.txt");
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You definitely do not want to read the entire file into a string if possible. The whole point of Streams is so you can work on them bits at a time - you don't want to load a 4GB file into RAM just to have the convenience of treating it like a string.

Comment: Do you really need to use the regex? You could read through the file (char by char) and use a bool switch to determine whether to keep the space char or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line-by-line, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}");   //Pattern = 2 or more space in a string.

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\CSharpProject\in\abc.txt"))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\CSharpProject\out\abc.txt"))
    {
       string content;
       while (null != (content = reader.ReadLine()));
          writer.WriteLine (pattern.Replace (content, " "));

       writer.Close();
       reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you lose the linebreaks with this code? `ReadLine` doesn't return the line separators, and you're using `Write`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, oops. My first draft did it wrong, caught it though.  Thanks

Comment: Thx, it works. But I've to replace the semicolon with a closing parenthese: while (null != (content = reader.ReadLine());

Comment: A side effect of this code is that it replaces the kind of line ending.

Answer (score 0):

The file is being read all at once.  There are limits.  Instead of reader.ReaderToEnd(), use reader.ReadLine() and read and process the file one line at a time.  Or if the file doesn't have "lines" read the input file in chunks and save the output chunks as it is being processed.